# Could not build wheels for rl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, windows, keras

Error while installing rl, I have been trying to install rl library on windows 10, python V3.9.6 and pip V23.0.1. Here is what I have

```
C:\Users\A>pip install rl
Collecting rl
  Using cached rl-3.1.tar.gz (443 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: rl
  Building wheel for rl (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for rl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl
      copying rl\testing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl
      copying rl\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl
      copying rl\_completion.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl
      copying rl\_history.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl
      copying rl\_init.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl
      copying rl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl\examples
      copying rl\examples\display_matches_hook.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl\examples
      copying rl\examples\email.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl\examples
      copying rl\examples\factory.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl\examples
      copying rl\examples\filename.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl\examples
      copying rl\examples\pre_input_hook.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl\examples
      copying rl\examples\raw_input.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl\examples
      copying rl\examples\static.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl\examples
      copying rl\examples\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rl\examples
      running build_ext
      WARNING: Failed to detect a termcap library; falling back to ncurses
      Un sous-r‚pertoire ou un fichier build existe d‚j….
      Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement deÿ: build.
      building 'rl.readline' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\build\readline
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\rl
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION=\"8.2\" -Ibuild -Ibuild/readline -Ic:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild/readline/bind.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\build/readline/bind.obj
      bind.c
      c1: fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier sourceÿ: 'build/readline/bind.c'ÿ: No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for rl
Failed to build rl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for rl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

all the libraries are installed accept the rl library. It's just showing this to install pyproject.toml error. Infact I have already done pip install pyproject.toml and it is installed then also it's showing the same error.

Many thanks for your help